# AttributeError: can't set attribute when adding substring to items in list

Tags: python

I want to add the `chr` substring to all items in the `clr_A0.chromnames` list.

```
import cooler
import cooltools.lib.plotting
import cooltools
from pathlib import Path


pathlist = Path(data_dir).glob('**/*.mcool')
for path in pathlist:
    
     cool_file = str(path)
     filename = cool_file.split("/",1)[1]    
     resolution = [i.rsplit("/", 1)[1] for i in cooler.fileops.list_coolers(cool_file)]
         
     ### load a cooler for each resolution 
     for j in resolution:
            if filename.startswith("A0"):
                clr_A0 = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
                clr_A0.chromnames = ["chr" + s for s in clr_A0.chromnames]
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 2>()
     10 if filename.startswith("A0"):
     11     clr_A0 = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
---> 12     clr_A0.chromnames = ["chr" + s for s in clr_A0.chromnames]

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Input:

`clr_A0.chromnames`

```
['M',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '12',
 '13',
 '14',
 '15',
 '16',
 '17',
 '18',
 '19',
 '20',
 '21',
 '22',
 'X',
 'Y']
```

Expected output:

```
['chrM',
 'chr1',
 'chr2',
 'chr3',
 'chr4',
 'chr5',
 'chr6',
 'chr7',
 'chr8',
 'chr9',
 'chr10',
 'chr11',
 'chr12',
 'chr13',
 'chr14',
 'chr15',
 'chr16',
 'chr17',
 'chr18',
 'chr19',
 'chr20',
 'chr21',
 'chr22',
 'chrX',
 'chrY']
```

Comment: If you look at the [implementation](https://cooler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/cooler/api.html#Cooler) it looks like `chromnames` is a property, which means that it isn't settable. How are you planning to use this? You could store it as a different attribute on the object, or in a local variable.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, you may be able to use [cooler.rename_chroms](https://cooler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#cooler.rename_chroms).

Comment: @PaulM. I'm not sure how to use it. I've tried

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`cooler.rename_chroms`](https://cooler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#cooler.rename_chroms) to change your chromnames. Use the existing cooler to generate the translation dict.

```py
clr_A0 = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
translations = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr_A0.chromnames}
cooler.rename_chroms(clr_A0, translations)
```

Comment: credit to Paul M. here who found the relevant method.